# How can I Connect two Linux virtual machine on VMware

Tags: linux, networking, vmware-workstation

I have Debian Server and Ubuntu 16.04, how can I connect them as client-server?

Comment: That’s not something VMware is concerned with. It can just connect them using a regular network link. Everything else is up to the software running on those VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect them to same network (ex: VMnet1) from VM->Settings->Network adapter

Answer (score 0):

Each machine would have its own name on the network, say frotto and goanna.  You would just talk from frotto to goanna in the same way that you do in a real network.

The network would be more of a home group, because there is no domain server.